# Getting metamask's pendent transaction count

Tags: contract-development, web3js, metamask

I am having problems to get the pending transaction counts on Metamask,

Do you know the method for the web3 API to get this?

I tried `web3.eth.filter('pending')` but it returns the pending transactions for the whole block and I only want the local instance.

It would be the number 2 on the top right corner:

[image: Metamask transaction count]

Comment: For a single address you can call `eth.getTransactionCount("0x12341234..", "pending")` to get all transactions including pending, then substract `eth.getTransactionCount("0x12341234..")` which returns already confirmed transactions.